# parse url parameters from html to php?

Tags: php, html, include, url-parameters, ssi

I have a website with a large amount of dynamic content. I have a main template page that then loads the content into it. I have SSI running fine (including to php files) but I cannot get the php files to see the url parameters from the html page. I would rather not convert all my html files to php files if I can help it.

The following code gets to the php file ok (ie displays hello world.) but what do I put for the ???? to get the topic passed from the html url to the included php file?

Ive tried $_GET which works if I call the page directly (ie place getDynamicContent.php?topic=X in the browser) but not when called through #include.

.

for a url: mainPage.shtml?topic=X

.

### in mainPage.shtml

```
//this includes fine - no problems
    <!--#include "commonHeaderStuff.html"-->

//this includes but does not parse variable
    <!--#include "getDynamicContent.php"-->
```

.

### in getDynamicContent.php

```
//get topic variable
    $topic=????

//return content based on $topic
    echo "hello world";
    if($topic=="X"){echo "You passes an X"}
    else {echo "You passes a Y";}
```

Comment: You have to use `$_GET` to get a variable from a URL parameter

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$_GET`

```
if(isset($_GET['topic'])){
    $topic = $_GET['topic'];
    echo "hello world";
    if($topic == "X"){
        echo "You passes an X";
    }else{
        echo "You passes a Y";
    }
}else{
    #no topic
}
```

Heres an attempt of mine by searching for a way to pass variables to a included from [Get url and parameters with SSI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5203110/1700963)

```
<!-- set default value for SSI variable "topic" -->    
<!--#set var="topic" value="" -->

<!-- get "topic" value from URL --> 
<!--#if expr="$QUERY_STRING = /topic=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/" -->
<!--#set var="topic" value="?topic=$1" -->
<!--#endif -->

<!--#include virtual="getDynamicContent.php${topic}"-->
```

I tested this just now and it works also I had to add `virtual=` to have it work but you might need to change it to `file=`. you can change `<!--#set var="topic" value="" -->` to whatever default value you want eg: `value="?topic=X"`

Comment: Thanks, Ive tried $_GET and it doesnt work. $_GET works ig I call the page directly (ie place getDynamicContent.php?topic=X in the browser) but not when called through #include.