# Why won't my PHP parse correctly?

Tags: php, .htaccess, compiler-errors, include, php-parse-error

I know the title is vague, but the details for this particular question would make the title absurd.

I have an `index.php` file that has a virtual include within it:

```
<!--#include virtual="/includes/header.include"-->
```

This `header.include` file is `HTML` and I want to add a few lines of `PHP` inside of it.

My `.htaccess` file is set up to process `.include` files as php.  The actual line from the `.htaccess` file is:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .include
```

The `PHP` that I'm trying to add is:

```
<?php echo "test <br />"; ?>
```

But when I load the website, the only thing that prints is:

`"; ?>`

If I view the source of the `index.php` I can see the entire `PHP` code that I have above.

Some other things I've already tried:

- Copy the `.htaccess` file into the directory that the `header.include` file is in
- [Both the accepted answer and the answer with 6 upvotes from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369781/htaccess-rule-to-parse-php-in-html-files-not-working)
- Tried `<br>` instead of `<br />`

What am I doing wrong?  Why won't the `PHP` get parsed correctly?

My `PHP` version is `5.1.6`

Comment: If you run the `header.include` file directly from the browser, does the PHP execute then? If it does, perhaps `#include` will not take any script interpreters into account?

Comment: ... that said, do check that your htaccess file is actually being read and processed.

Comment: the line: Use <br> instead of <br/> is not correct.  Rather the <br> tag can be self closed (rather that having a second tag </br>)  the correct format is <br /> <== note the space before the '/'    Why make the include 'virtual' when a simple <?php include /includes/header.include ?>   BTW: is that includes sub directory really at the file system root?  probably not, so a better line might be: rename the file to header.php  then include it with: <?php ./includes/header.php ?>

Comment: @halfer - no.. the doc isnt found.. thats why the include virtual command was used... it points somewhere away from the html doc root.  thats why i tried to copy the htaccess file over

Comment: @user3629249 -if you read the things ive tried, that was one of them... <br> also doesn't work

Comment: I've found a workaround for my problem on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733053/get-url-and-parameters-with-ssi